# PDO: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making an IS and I have a problem with updating mysql table. I'm using PHP 5.3 and PDO.

```
            $query_update = $this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE Client SET name =: name, surname=:surname WHERE id=:id');
            $query_update->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query_update->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_update->bindValue(':surname', $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_update->execute();
```

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in file on line X.
The Warning is referencing line with execute().

Thanks for help.

EDIT: It's working now, again thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a space too much. Correct you query to this:

```
$this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE Client SET name =:name, surname=:surname WHERE id=:id');
// -----------------------------------------------------^
```

This lead to only two variables being used in the query, which didn't match the 3 variables you provided.

(Your query in the current form should throw an error anyways at the same position.)